# Emular navegação

Tags: javascript

Queria saber se existe alguma forma de eu emular navegação por uma página, assim como fazem o [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) ou o [HttpURLConection](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html), nos quais eu posso requisitar outras páginas através deles.
Existe alguma forma de eu requisitar e ir navegação pelas páginas (que não estão no meu domínio) para minerar essas informações?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar a ferramenta [Puppeteer](https://pptr.dev/), que é basicamente um Google Chrome com uma interface exposta em métodos JavaScript.

Com um simples script você pode coletar informações de qualquer página web (desde que seja pública ou você tenha uma forma de acesso). O exemplo a seguir coleta o nome do autor de uma pergunta no StackOverflow:

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  try {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();

    // Abrimos uma nova página:
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/88472/69296');

    // Recuperamos o elemento que possui o autor da página, em seguida, o texto.
    const element = await page.$('div.user-details > a');
    const text = await page.evaluate((el) => el.textContent, element);

    console.log(`Autor da pergunta: ${text}.`);

    await browser.close();
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error.message);
  }
})();
```

Deixei um [repositório de exemplo](https://github.com/lffg-archive/sopt-88472) disponível no GitHub.

---

A biblioteca é um pouco complicada, já que os métodos são um pouco diferente do costume. Mas a documentação cobre diversos casos. :)

[Este vídeo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pixfH6yyqZk) (em inglês) mostra exemplos um pouco mais complexos usando essa biblioteca.